# How do I Project an Array Field with Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to create an aggregation pipeline using Spring Data MongoDB that projects a new array field into the pipeline.  How can I accomplish this using Spring Data?

The Pipeline stage I am trying to replicate is as follows:

```
{
    $project: {
        "aceId": 1,     
        "startActivityDateTime": 1,
        "lastActivityDateTime": 1, 
        "eventInfo": [ 
            "$applicationInfo", 
            "$riskAssessmentInfo", 
            "$policyInfo", 
            "$submissionInfo"
        ] 
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem and found a Solution. You have to create a CustomAggregationOperation class as in this answer suggested:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29186539/5033846

```
public class CustomProjectAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomProjectAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
```

}

Then you can achieve your projection stage as follows:

```
new CustomAggregationOperation(new BasicDBObject("$project",
    new BasicDBObject("aceId", 1)
      .appending("startActivityDateTime", 1)
      .appending("lastActivityDateTime", 1)
      .appending("eventInfo", 
         new Object[]{
           "$applicationInfo", 
           "$riskAssessmentInfo", 
           "$policyInfo", 
           "$submissionInfo"}
       )
));
```

Comment: This is a very low-level way of doing this, just fyi.

Comment: @Madbreaks please propose a better solution

Comment: Use the aggregation API, which exposes methods like `project(...)`.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation