# MongoDB + Spring: Aggregation with multiple group by and sums

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I have my MongoDB query which returns the expected Data but I'm struggling to translate it with Spring (org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate).

Let's say in my collection A I have this document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("12345"),
    "name" : "someCoolName",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-03-15T17:35:00.000Z"),
    "notes" : [ 
        {
            "description" : "A lot of description",
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2023-03-07T09:35:00.000Z"),
            "counter" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Bit less description",
            "dueDate" : ISODate("2023-03-15T17:35:00.000Z"),
            "counter" : 1
        }, 
    ]
}
```

And in my collection B I have this linked document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("67890"),
    "idNotes" : ObjectId("12345"), //id of document from collection A
    "counter" : 0,
    "review" : "amazing"
}
```

I built a query which extracts all documents where note's arrays size doesn't match the number of results found in collection B by idNotes .
Here's my MongoDB query:

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
{ $lookup: {
  from: 'collectionB',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'idNotes',
  as: 'documentB'
}}, 
{ $group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  fromB: { $sum: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$documentB" }, then: { $size: "$documentB" }, else: 0} }},
  numberOfNotes: {$sum: {$cond: { if: { $isArray: "$notes" }, then: { $size: "$notes" }, else: 0} }}, 
"updatedAt": { $first: "$updatedAt" }
}},
{ $match: {
  $expr: {$ne: ["$fromB", "$numberOfNotes"]}
}},
{ $sort : { "updatedAt" : -1 }}
])
```

May you help me with this? I'm stuck with things like

```
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("documentB").sum("$size: documentB").as("fromB");
```

but I don't understand how / what is the best approach to add the other groupBy conditions.

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like:

```java
GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.
    group("_id")
        .sum("fromB",
            Cond(isArray("documentB"),size("documentB"),0)
        ).as("fromB")
        .sum("numberOfNotes",
            Cond(isArray("notes"),size("notes"),0)
        ).as("numberOfNotes")
        .first("updatedAt").as("updatedAt");
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you! But what is cond ? I mean, it's the Condition object, but where/how did you init it? I found ref like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186185/how-to-use-cond-operation-in-spring-mongodb-aggregation-framework] this answer but it doesn't seem to check the size, but just values, so I think it doesn't suite my case.

Comment: `cond` is from [ConditionalOperators.Cond](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ConditionalOperators.Cond.html). So capital letter is necessary. By the way I've not tested at all, maybe another little change is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I see. Like brackets size("documentB", 0). Thank you for your input in anycase. Since I've never seen this ConditionOperators, may you help me with your code snippet please? I really prefer your approach to the one I linked in the first comment